# Importing NSMutable Array into Map Annotations

Tags: annotations, nsmutablearray, mapkit

Hi all i have a mysql database that consists of 7 columns and i have a script that reads it and extracts the data as JSON which i have pulled into an NSMutableArray, I want to be able to use this array to setup annotations on my Map but i'm not sure what to do here, as you can see i have defined one annotation here which shows up no problem but i'm honestly not sure how to show the NSMutableArray items? The NSMutable array will have more information than needed for the Annotations, I only need, coordinate, title and subtitle so how can i go about doing this? Here is my code so far:

hazards.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Hazards : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ROUTE;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ADDRESS;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * LATITUDE;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * LONGITUDE;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * HAZARD;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * RISK;

// Methods
- (id) initWithID: (NSString *) hazardsID andROUTE: (NSString *) hazardsROUTE andADDRESS: (NSString *) hazardsADDRESS andLATITUDE: (NSString *) hazardsLATITUDE andLONGITUDE: (NSString *) hazardsLONGITUDE andHAZARD: (NSString *) hazardsHAZARD andRISK: (NSString *) hazardsRISK;

@end
```

hazards.m

```
#import "Hazards.h"

@implementation Hazards
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle, ID, ROUTE, ADDRESS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, HAZARD, RISK;

- (id) initWithID: (NSString *) hazardsID andROUTE: (NSString *) hazardsROUTE andADDRESS: (NSString *) hazardsADDRESS andLATITUDE: (NSString *) hazardsLATITUDE andLONGITUDE: (NSString *) hazardsLONGITUDE andHAZARD: (NSString *) hazardsHAZARD andRISK: (NSString *) hazardsRISK {

    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        ID = hazardsID;
        ROUTE = hazardsROUTE;
        ADDRESS = hazardsADDRESS;
        LATITUDE = hazardsLATITUDE;
        LONGITUDE = hazardsLONGITUDE;
        HAZARD = hazardsHAZARD;
        RISK = hazardsRISK;
    }
return self;
}

@end
```

viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "Hazards.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *json;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *hazardsArray;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

#pragma mark - Methods
-(void) retrieveData;

@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Hazards.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

// Railway Street Ballymena Coordinates
#define BALLYMENA_LATITUDE 54.857719;
#define BALLYMENA_LONGITUDE -6.280654;

// Span
#define THE_SPAN 0.01f;

#define getDataURL @"localhost:8888/rmb/json.php"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize json, hazardsArray, mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    // Center
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = BALLYMENA_LATITUDE;
    center.longitude = BALLYMENA_LONGITUDE;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = center;
    myRegion.span = span;

    // Set our mapview
    [mapView setRegion:myRegion animated: YES];

    // Annotation
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    Hazards *myAnn;

    // Pin to show Royal Mail Ballymena delivery office
    myAnn = [[Hazards alloc] init];
    location.latitude = BALLYMENA_LATITUDE;
    location.longitude = BALLYMENA_LONGITUDE;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"Royal Mail Ballymena";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"111, Railway Street";
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];

    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Methods
-(void) retrieveData {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    // Setup our hazards array
    hazardsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i =0; i < json.count; i++) {

        // Create hazard object
        NSString *hazardsID = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID"];
        NSString *hazardsROUTE = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ROUTE"];
        NSString *hazardsADDRESS = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ADDRESS"];
        NSString *hazardsLATITUDE = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"];
        NSString *hazardsLONGITUDE = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"LONGITUDE"];
        NSString *hazardsHAZARD = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"HAZARD"];
        NSString *hazardsRISK = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"RISK"];

        Hazards *myHazards = [[Hazards alloc] initWithID:hazardsID andROUTE:hazardsROUTE andADDRESS:hazardsADDRESS andLATITUDE:hazardsLATITUDE andLONGITUDE:hazardsLONGITUDE andHAZARD:hazardsHAZARD andRISK:hazardsRISK];

        // Add our hazards object to our hazards array
        [hazardsArray addObject:myHazards];
    }
    // [self.mapView addAnnotation:hazardsArray];
}

@end
```

Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `retrieveData` correctly builds Hazard objects and is called at the right time you could either add them one at a time with this line inside the loop

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:myHazards];
```

or all at once after the loop is finished

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:hazardsArray];
```